# jQuery Slow in IE to do a mouseover on a TR

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

When the mouse hovers over the TR, we want to show a hidden DIV. We could bind this function to the TR with jQuery but this is just done at the server side:

```
<tr onmouseover="displayDIV('0123456789');" onmouseout="hideDIV('0123456789');" ...

 function displayDIV(rowID) {
    $('#options'+rowID).css('visibility','visible');
 }

 function hideDIV(rowID) {
    $('#options'+rowID).css('visibility','hidden');
 }
```

This is fast in Chrome, but very slow in IE. How can this be improved?

Comment: I think it should be pointed out, even though you've excluded the option, that using event handler would be considerably faster. Maybe you should reconsider this decision.

Comment: @Yi: how did the OP exclude that option?

Comment: I don't understand "this is just done at the server side". Surely you don't mean the onmouseover/onmouseout functions? or did you mean client side?

Answer (score 0):

If you use

```
$('#options'+rowID).show()
```

and

```
$('#options'+rowID).hide()
```

rather than setting CSS properties directly, does the performance improve?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've not tried this because it's not suitable - we don't want display none as content will jump about.

Comment: Just tried it, still slow. We have a tr:hover in CSS, in IE this lags behind as each function is called, in Chrome, no lag.

Comment: @Igor: Oh yeah. I forgot that "hide" can mean two different things... display=none vs. visibility=hidden.